# Oracle: Having join or simple from/where clause has no affect on performance?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g

My manger just told me that having joins or where clause in oracle query doesn't affect performance even when you have million records in each table. And I am just not satisfied with this and want to confirm that.
which of the following queries is better in performance on oracle and in postgresql also

1-

```
select a.name,b.salary,c.address 
    from a,b,c
    where a.id=b.id and a.id=c.id;
```

2-

```
select a.name,b.salary,c.address 
    from a
    JOIN b on a.id=b.id
    JOIN C on a.id=c.id;
```

I have tried Explain in postgresql for a small data set and query time was same (may be because I have just few rows) and right now I have no access to oracle and actual database to analyze the Explain in real envoirnment.

Comment: I think you're missing something fundamental here - both of your queries join the three tables, and in exactly the same way - the difference is just in syntax. `FROM a, b` is semantically identical to `FROM a CROSS JOIN b`. Your manager is correct, as long as the query plans are the same, I'd expect the performance to be identical  (all else being equal).

Comment: @JeffreyKemp:: I am not missing anything just want to know that both queries has same performance or not in oracle or not?And same if both has same performance for postgresql or not? when dealing with large dataset

Comment: @JeffreyKemp:: it means having join or where clause will not affect performance in oracle?

Comment: I don't know about postgresql, but in Oracle, they are the same statement, just different syntax. `FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id` probably gets rewritten to `FROM a,b WHERE a.id=b.id`; it means exactly the same thing anyway.

Comment: Generally the ANSI syntax (`JOIN` etc) is preferable unless you're on a very old version of the database. There are some joins that can be tricky to do in the old syntax, but easier with the ANSI syntax - e.g. outer joins.

Comment: @Elvin For both Oracle and Postgres the queries will have the same execution plan -> same performance. To check it yourself - just generate and compare execution plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using `JOINS` makes the code easier to read, since it's self-explanatory.
2. In speed there is no difference (I have just tested it) and the execution plan is the same
3. If the query optimizer is doing its job right, there should be no difference between those queries. 
   They are just two ways to specify the same desired result.

Comment: because then it means that joins in oracle/postgresql are just for readability purpose which is not digested to me

Comment: in oracle i have data with 200+ rows,when exe on them i see no difference

Comment: Using joins makes the code easier to read and I generally always use it since the structure of the statement better describes the datamodel. However, please note that using ANSI-style joins in more complex statements can have a major drawback on PARSE time (not on execution time) since Oracle Corp. itself seems to focus it's testing on Oracle style joins. This especially holds for outer joins. With outer joins you can run into unexpected Full Table Scans not occurring with Oracle style joins. Esp when outer joining with two tables (which is actually not possible with Oracle style outer joins).